# How does containsKey really work in Java when working with Map?

Tags: java

How does **containsKey** really work? I know that if I do this:

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("user1", 1);
 map.put("user2", 2);
 map.put("user3", 3);

 System.out.println(map.containsKey("user1")); // true
```

**containsKey** returns **true**

but If I do this:

```
Map<Person, Integer> table = new HashMap<>();
table.put(new Person("Steve"), 33);
table.put(new Person("Mark"), 29);

System.out.println(table.containsKey(new Person("Steve"))); // false
```

so why am I getting **false** even if I have the correct key? How do I check for value of 33 by using its key?

Comment: Because your `Person` class doesn't (correctly) implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: Because you haven't implemented `equals()` on your class Java can only check to see if the 2 objects reference the same memory. This explains how equality works in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Here you are using String as key

`Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`

`map.put("user1", 1);`

And `String` class ia implementing `HashCode` and `Equals` method and hence it is working as expected.

While you are using `Person` class object as key or any custom class, you should make sure that you override `Hashcode` and `equals` method.

`HashMap` implemention uses `hashCode` to find bucket and the uses `equals` if there are multiple entries present in bucket.

Answer (score 1):

When working with maps all the objects that need to be stored in the map should implement **equals and hashcode**

Here is sample Person class that behaves as you would expect:

```
class Person {
        private String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Person)) {
                return false;
            }

            Person other = (Person) obj;

            return other.getName().equals(this.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return this.name.hashCode();
        }

    }
```

HashMap uses equals() to compare whether the keys are equal or not
hashCode() is used to calculate the index in which the item should be inserted